# Switch controlled drivers

Tags: texturing, drivers, append

I have a surface in an object that I want to be a light, one that can be turned on and off, not blinking, but more like a light switch.  I have figured out how to drive the light, the emission value, using an another objects attribute as a driver.  So if a Plain Axis X position is 0 the light is off, if it is 1 then the light is on.  However this is cludgy, when I want to append the object with the light into another blend I have to remember to bring the Plain Axis object as well.

Is there a better or more tidy way of bringing a driver driven surface (or any driver driven thing) into another blender and bring the source driver with it? Even as a switch some where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [custom property](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/custom_properties.html) to the light object, and refer to that in your driver. That way you don't have to depend on another object.

Answer (score 1):

This will largely depend on how you set yourself up to re-use assets.

I personally like to put this kind of stuff in its own file, and create a group of everything needed. Save Save Save.

Then in my main working file I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> browse to my particular asset file. Double click on it. Then double click on groups. Then select my desired group name and pull it in.